# TextEditingController return to old value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the StatefulWidget widget i have a TextFormField and it's controller like below:

```
class _RequestInfoWidgetState extends State<RequestInfoWidget> {
  TextEditingController requestInfoCtl1;
  @override
  void initState() {
    requestInfoCtl1 = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
            _showBottomSheetDates(context, requestInfoCtl1);
          },
          controller: requestInfoCtl1,
          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Start Date",
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
        ),
```

When tapped on TextFiled `_showBottomSheetDates` called and i show my date picker in modal bottomsheet:

```
  _showBottomSheetDates(BuildContext cntext, TextEditingController controller) {
    showModalBottomSheetCustom(
        context: cntext,
        mHeight: 0.95,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return initDatePicker(controller);
        });
  }

  initDatePicker(TextEditingController controller) {
    persianDatePicker = PersianDatePicker(
      controller: controller,
      datetime: Jalali.now().toString(),
      fontFamily: 'IranSans',
      farsiDigits: true,
      onChange: (String oldText, String newText) {
        controller.text = newText;
      },
    ).init();
    return persianDatePicker;
  }
```

but when i select my date from DatePicker and `BottomSheet` is closed the value of `requestInfoCtl1` returned into old value and new value is gone??

Comment: in the official docs TextEditingController is initialized at the top of the widget not in InitState() Maybe this is the problem Also Try SetState()
refer to official docs 
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check

```
setState(() {
  controller.text = newText;
});
```